# Meaning of "since changed"

Tags: meaning

> The MVC in Backbone originally stood for Models, Views and
>   Collections, since there were no controllers in the framework. This
>   has **since changed**.

Does it mean it has changed from that moment or it has changed from that time to the present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It has changed from that time, to the time this was written." Which might be present. =)

Answer (score 2):

"It has since changed" could be reworded as "It has changed *since then*".